# Using regular expression extractor to extract a value?

Tags: regex, jmeter

[image][image]I am trying to extract the value from the following code. Even though my regex expression is fine it is still not extracting the value.

```
token" value="(.+?)"
```

this does give me the exact match which I checked using regex101.com

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="GSYGEP2UUWOTMZ2SFV1G5D2M8L247KIG">
```

what the regex expression should be

Comment: I'd be interested to see how the response driven regex accomplishes this. It must be via a DOM or something. If the duplicate did not answer your question, let me know and I'll open it back up.

Comment: the duplicate did not work

Comment: Can you show the response you are trying to extract?

Answer (score 0):

Your original regular expression is just fine:

```
value="(.+?)"
```

It might be additional spaces, or code problems with it. Let's remove the `token"` or try to escape `"`, if necessary.

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/0C2HBl/1)

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/WUOkOJ/1)

#### Reference:

- [Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

Comment: ive tried those as well but the "value" appears multiple time in the element so i can't use just "value" by itself therefore, i added token"

Comment: no it still does not give me the value just returns with the default value

Comment: Still no luck, i am going to add screenshots of all my Jmeter entry in the question please check if i am doing all that correctly.

Comment: i tried his way as well im not sure what it could be

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sname\s*=\s*(['"])\s*token\s*\1)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\svalue\s*=\s*(['"])((?:(?!\2)[\S\s])*)\2)\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>
```

The Value content you're after is in *`Capture Group 3`*

https://regex101.com/r/HJhStT/1
https://regex101.com/r/8BWONb/1

Explained

```
 < input                # Input tag

 (?=                    # Name attribute: Assert (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s name  \s* = \s*     # name = 
      ( ['"] )               # (1), Quote
      \s* token \s*          # token
      \1 
 )
 (?=                    # Value attribute
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s value  \s* = \s*    # value =
      ( ['"] )               # (2), Quote
      (                      # (3 start), value content
           (?:
                (?! \2 )
                [\S\s] 
           )*
      )                      # (3 end)
      \2 
 )
 # Just get rest of tag
 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+
 >
```

Comment: I tried this but it just responds with the default value.

Comment: Here is the link with the full code to see if i am not missing anything [link](https://regex101.com/r/kL5JcE/1)

Comment: @owaiskhan - The Value content you're after is in _`Capture Group 3`_. See https://regex101.com/r/HJhStT/1

Comment: how can i make my regular expression to capture only group 3?

Comment: @owaiskhan - You can't, but why would that even matter ?

Comment: It still returns with only the default value, it is not extracting the "value", any suggestions?

Comment: Sure, I suggest you take one or both of these tests https://regex101.com/r/HJhStT/1
https://regex101.com/r/8BWONb/1 and modify it with your data that fails, then fork the result and show me the link in a comment. Otherwise, I have no idea what your talking about ...